# Can Carbon be a metal?

Tags: solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory, metals

If we define a metal as:

> A material that has a partially filled band at $T=0$ (assuming ambient pressure).

Carbon has a valance of 4 and has 4 orbitals that are accessible. From this we can determine if a given crystal of C is a insulator or metal (or semiconductor) for example:

> Diamond has two different carbon environments and thus has $8$
>   different bands. In diamond however there is a split between the
>   bottom 4 and top 4, the bottom 4 are filled and the top 4 are empty. Diamond is, therefore, an insulator.

My question is - is it possible to create a crystal of carbon such that there are sufficient overlapping bands that so that we it conducts electricity?

<sub>I have a feeling this may be the case for graphene if this is so please can you explain its band structure of why.</sub>

Comment: Ambient pressure? In principle every solid becomes metallic under a high enough pressure.

Comment: @JohnRennie I didn't actually know that - thanks. Yes so for the purpose of this question we will assume ambient pressure.

Comment: Wikipedia about [Carbon nanotubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_nanotube): In particular, their band gap can vary from zero to about 2 eV and their electrical conductivity can show metallic or semiconducting behavior.